# Why did Sauron's spirit reform in Mirkwood?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, sauron

When Sauron was defeated in the War of the Last Alliance at the end of the Second Age, why did his spirit reform in Mirkwood and not elsewhere? Did Sauron have some sort of connection with Mirkwood that meant that he could reform there, or was he able to choose from anywhere and simply chose Mirkwood for some sort of advantage it would give him?

EDIT: To be more specific, I would like to know why Sauron fled to Mirkwood despite there still being elves in its northern area.

Comment: He likes forests; as Thu in the First Age he inhabited Taur-na-Fuin in Dorthonion  (also translated as "Mirkwood", among other things!) after being kicked out of his body by Huan in Beren & Luthien.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sauron did not die at the end of the Third Age.  Elrond – an eyewitness – puts it that

> Sauron himself was overthrown

not "died".  Gandalf says that with the destruction of the Ring

> ...then he [Sauron] will fall; and his fall will be so low that none can foresee his arising ever again. For he will lose the best part of the strength that was native to him in his beginning, and all that was made or begun with that power will crumble, and he will be maimed for ever, becoming a mere spirit of malice that gnaws itself in the shadows, but cannot again grow or take shape. And so a great evil of this world will be removed.

Sauron did not die either time – he cannot be killed by any agency in Arda, only diminished – and his fall after his defeat by Gil-Galad, Elendil and Isildur was a lesser fall than after the Ring was destroyed. (At the end of the Third Age, he was to embody himeself once again, but after the destruction of the Ring he could not, yet still survived as a "mere spirit of malice.")

It is perfectly plausible that after the Last Alliance, once Sauron had recovered some of his diminished being in the long course of time, he was able to move his disembodied spirit and choose where in Arda he became re-embodied.

So Mirkwood was probably his choice, not an accident.  So why Mirkwood? Gondor was still strong enough that had he set up shop in Barad-Dur he'd have been noticed. He needed to pick a place which was still on the playing field of western Middle-Earth, one not previously associated with him (secrecy and misdirection!), and one with no troublesome neighbors.

(I suspect that he could have also chosen some of the more abandoned parts of Eriador an perhaps some of the more desolate places in the North.  But Mirkwood is probably a better location from a strategic point of view.)

Comment: More importantly, Dol Guldur was near the last known location of the One Ring, *despite* its proximity to Lothlórien.

Comment: I don't think his spirit ever left Arda. He simply fled from his body. Spirits are generally able to move on their own, even in a crippled state. For example, Sauron's spirit fled Numenor after the Downfall.

Comment: @Shamshiel Quite right.  I meant to say where he became re-embodied. I have edited the answer.